# Touch в unity3d.Как при загрузки другой сцены не заcчитывать зажатый touch с первой?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код , который при нажатии на экран двигает персонажа :

```
 if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            go = 1;
        }
```

Фишка в том что если игрок побеждает  при этом не отпускает палец с экрана , то на следующем уровне(другой сцене) персонаж автоматически начинает двигаться .
Нужно сделать так что бы ,если игрок не отпустил палец с первой сцены ,то персонаж не двигался.

Comment: А как он двигается, уже после того как игрок убрал палец с экрана? Или если нажать и держать?

Comment: @trollingchar Когда игрок нажал.Если он будет продолжать держать палец то объект автоматично двигается , даже если и был переход на след. сцену ,так как условие if (Input.touchCount > 0) является верным

Comment: то есть надо просто сделать чтобы персонаж при таком поведении игрока не двигался? Ну в том смысле что он же не двигается если игрок не нажимает ничего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, у вас есть скрипт сцены и скрипт движения игрока. Сделайте скрипт движения игрока по умолчанию *выключенным*. В скрипте сцены проверяйте касания и включайте компонент, если их нет:

```
playerMovementScript.enabled |= Input.touchCount == 0;
```

Пока игрок не уберет пальцы с экрана, его персонаж не сдвинется с места, так как у выключенного скрипта движения не вызывается `Update`.

---

Если нельзя выключить скрипт движения игрока из-за того, что там делается что-то еще, можно сделать в нем флаг

```
public bool CanMove;
```

По умолчанию логический тип хранит `false`. В скрипте сцены пишем:

```
playerMovementScript.CanMove |= Input.touchCount == 0;
```

А логику движения помещаем внутрь блока `if`:

```
if (CanMove) {
    Move ();
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том , что я не могу выключить скрипт движения (Там не только логика движения игрока , но и другие важные вещи).

Comment: @Veudd я понял. Сейчас скажу как можно сделать по-другому.

Comment: @Veudd я добавил второе решение.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ пользователя trollingchar был крайне полезен , но я хочу добавить ещё один вариант ответа :
Начну с того , что логика движения и считывание тачей находятся в одном скрипте(хотя можно немного изменить код и логика может быть в другом скрипте)
При нажатии на экран touch будет равен 1 , тогда условие `if(Input.touchCount > 0)` ,будет верно и персонаж будет двигаться :

```
 if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
                         go = 1;    
        }
```

Для того чтобы персонаж не начал двигаться на следующей сцене без повторного нажатия(Если игрок нажал на экран и не отпустил палец , то на следующей сцене персонаж не начнет движение) нужно добавить переменную типа `bool`.

```
bool CanMove;



if (CanMove)
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {

                     go = 1;
                     CanMove = false;

    }
}
```

Теперь если `CanMove = true` и `Input.touchCount > 0` , то персонаж начнет движение и после `CanMove` будет `= false`(но у нас с самого начала `bool = false` и персонаж не начнет движение и поэтому нам нужно чтобы `CanMove` при  `if (Input.touchCount == 0)` был равен `true`

А теперь весь код :

```
bool CanMove;
void Start()
   {
       go = 0;
   }

 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        {
            CanMove = true;
        }

    if (CanMove)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {

                         go = 1;
                         CanMove = false;      
        }
    }
}
```